# Couldn't change the Country and Region on my iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am unable to change the Country and Region on my iPhone. Upon attempting, the following message is displayed:

[image]

What could be the possible cause? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you make sure you do not have any outstanding store credit left in your account? Kindly review through the information under "What to do before changing your country or region" mentioned on the Apple Support document, [Change your Apple ID country or region](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201389).

Answer (score 1):

There could be numerous reasons for that error. So, a good starting point is to make sure you check all the below mentioned points-

- Ensure that there is no Store credit remaining in your Apple ID.
- Check whether any refund is in progress associated to your Apple ID.
- Turn OFF all the subscriptions that you have for various services with your Apple ID.
- Make sure you are not in a Family Sharing group.

Once you are assured with all the above points, you can try changing your Country or Region now. In addition, make sure to enter the correct details, especially Payment information, Address, and Phone.